# Azureに構築したEthereumの環境と接続について

Tags: azure, ethereum

Azureに「Ethereum Proof-of-Work Consortium」を使用してノードをあげました

ですが分からないこと2点あります

１.プライベートネットには出来ないのか?
基本設定で「Deploy a network that will be part of a consortium?」
を「Standalone」にしたのですが、これはプライベートネットではないのでしょうか
Consortiumと言うくらいなので他のノードも参加しているテストネットなのでしょうか

２.gethからの接続方法

```
$ geth --networkid "構築時に設定したID" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr "トランザクションノードパブリックIP" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal"
```

以下のエラーが出ました

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp トランザクションノードパブリックIP:8545: bind: can't assign requested address
```

正しい接続方法教えていただけないでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました

プライベートネットとするために、Azureでの構築途中で、genesis blockを使うように設定
Attributeの順番が決まっている様(いくつかパターンがある)なので注意

```
alloc
config
coinbase
```

の順で私は設定しました

起動後の接続方法ですが、gethで直接繋がらないので、
一旦トランザクションノードへssh
port 22だと駄目なので、4000を使用

```
ssh -p 4000 VM user Name@パブリックIP
```

ログイン後、geth接続
ローカルIPを使用
ただし、localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0は駄目でした

```
geth attach http://ローカルIP:8545
```

これで接続出来ました

pythonからweb3pyを使い外部からの接続も出来ました

```
W3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://パブリックIP:8545'))
```